# Hiding and showing multiple selects

Tags: jquery

I have 2 selects, and I want to remove, based on the values from second select, values from first. For example: if I select value 1 and 2 from second select, I want that values 2,3,4,5 are hidden, and if in the second select value is 3, I want that values 1,2,3 are hidden:

Select1:

```
<select name="select1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Select2:

```
<select name="select2">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

This is the code for hiding in the case that is selected 1 or 2:

```
var ary=[2,3,4,5];
$('[name=select1] option').filter(function(){
return ($.inArray(parseInt(this.value),ary) >-1);}).hide();
```

This code works for hiding, but I have a problem. When the code hides 2,3,4,5 on value 1 and 2, selecting value 3 in second select shows me only value 1, because others are hidden. I solved this using show(). And then 2,3,4,5 are showed but I can't hide value 1 because of the return :// I tried this, it won't work:

```
var ary=[4,5];
var ary2=[1];
$('[name=select1] option').filter(function(){
return ($.inArray(parseInt(this.value),ary) >-1);}).hide()&&($.inArray(parseInt(this.value),arry2) >-1);}).show();
```

I also tried to call another function which would always refresh select1 , showing it all values, and in this functions only to use hides, I think that wouldbe right way, but I don't know how to solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this question.  You only want to show elements in `select1` that are selected in `select2`?  Can you explain this a little more?

Comment: I think you can use [jquery cascade](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/cascade) and just switch the sets of options available for each of dropdown.

Comment: @RocketHazmat i just want to remove values on select1. if selected value on select2 is 1 or 2 i want to hide values 2,3,4,5 form select1. if selected value on select2 is 3, i want to remove values 1,2,3.

Comment: mine code works fine for hiding, problem is how to show then value 4,5 AND remove value 1,2,3 when i select value 3. i think that it would be best to always use hide in mine function and to use some function which would refresh this select1, and set all his values to show(), and after that to run mine function, and then to hide values 2,3,4,5 for select2=1 or 2, and hide 1,2,3 for select2=3 any clearer???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZuGE/

Note, the adding list items I guess could be a bit more efficient here, but you get the idea:

```
var $resetValues = $('#select1').find("option");

$('#select2').on('change', function() {
    var selected = $("option:selected", this).val();
    // Reset select1
    $('#select1').empty();
    $resetValues.each(function() {
         $('#select1').append($(this));
    });

    var array; // Hidden values
    if(selected > 0 && selected < 3) {
        array = [2,3,4,5];
    } else {
        array = [1,2,3];
    }

    $('#select1 option').filter(function() {
        return ($.inArray(parseInt($(this).val()), array) != -1);
    }).remove();
});
```

Comment: tnx a lot men, you helped me a lot, i was starting to get grey on my head :) i change a bit your code, check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/8ZuGE/10/